# Changing page subtitle using the URI in Menus?

Tags: filter, menu, orocrm

I have an application-menu item that I added that contains a URI with a custom filter in attached to the page name (aka URI Querystring).  I would like to have the page subtitle change to represent this filtered data on the page.

Has anyone done any work like this or have an easy way to set the page subtitle using the application-menu items?

Here is what is getting called in the browser:

```
<h1 class="oro-subtitle" id="grid-title-contacts-grid2073">All Contacts</h1>
```

Here is what is in the URI (decoded)

> /contact?grid[contacts-grid]=i=1&p=25&s[lastName]=-1&s[firstName]=-1&f[__duplicate]=0&f[contactType][type]=1&f[contactType][value][]=PCM&c=id0.firstName1.lastName1.birthday0.gender0.email1.phone1.fax0.skype0.twitter0.facebook0.linkedIn0.googlePlus0.source1.countryName1.regionLabel1.addressPostalCode1.addressCity0.addressStreet0.createdAt1.updatedAt1.pictureFilename0.ownerName0.assignedName0.reportsName0.timesContacted0.timesContactedIn0.timesContactedOut0.lastContactedDate0.lastContactedDateIn0.lastContactedDateOut0.daysSinceLastContact0.contactType1.dateOfBirth1.PCMStatusContact1.tags1&v=**all**&a=grid

Answer (score 0):

You can save the grid view and give it a custom title.
Here is the documentation on how to do that: https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/getting-started/navigation/record-tables/#create-saved-table-views-grid-views

Then copy the URL for the page and use it for the menu item. It should now redirect to the saved view with your title.